# Matplotlib : Impossible to set 0.0 and 1.0 on right ytick values outside a subplot

Tags: python, numpy, precision, xticks

I am trying to display the yticks `0.0` and `1.0` on right y axis of a  subplot (instead of `0` and `1`)

Here what I have done (with `m` and `n` the rows/columns of graph) :

```
 ax = g.subplots[m,n]
 ax.yaxis.tick_right()
 ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('right')
 ax.set_yticks([float(0), float(1)])
```

and the result is :

[image: plot]

I thought that it would be a conflict with the red upper title but even if I take a smaller font size, prollem remains, impossible to make display `0.0` and `1.0` instead of `0` and `1`.

The plot above represents the 1/2 sigma confidence levels coming from a covariance matrix with joint distributions. It is produced by  [Getdist tool](https://getdist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

The main routine that generates this plot is :

```
g.triangle_plot([matrix1, matrix2],
                  names,
                  filled = True,
                  legend_labels = ['1240', '1560'],
                  legend_loc = 'upper right',
                  contour_colors = ['darkblue','red'],
                  line_args = [{'lw':2, 'color':'darkblue'},
                  {'lw':2, 'color':'red'}]
                  )
```

and after, I modify each box by doing the double loop :

```
# Browse each subplot of triangle
  for m in range(0,7):
    for n in range(0,m+1):
      ax = g.subplots[m,n]
      ax.tick_params(axis='both', direction='out', length=5, width=1)
```

in which I did what I have shown at the beginning of my post :

```
 ax.yaxis.tick_right()
 ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('right')
 ax.set_yticks([float(0), float(1)])
```

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney I have added the main function and extra that I have used with GetDist tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `set_yticklabels(['0.0', '1.0'])`